# Regex : every alphanumeric subdomains, except www

Tags: php, regex

This is a piece of a big regex (php) :

```
((?:[0-9A-z_-]+))
```

I use it to valid a subdomain, but I would like to accept every subdomains **except** "www"

How can I do that when there's an alphanumeric "selector" ?

EDIT : Finally used `(\b(?!www\b)(?:[0-9A-Za-z_-]+))`, thanks to Tim and ATS

Comment: Try `(?!www)`. [More info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html) (go to paragraph 'Finding Lines Containing or Not Containing Certain Words')

Comment: _Almost_, but not completely, a duplicate of [Regex for ANY string except “www”? (subdomain)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7099397/2936460).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
((?!www)(?:[0-9A-Za-z_-]+))
```

This uses negative lookahead to say "not www".

This assumes that the rest of the regex (as you wrote, it's part of a bigger expression) makes sure that this part contains *just* a possible subdomain. So this part should match *all* of a subdomain but shouldn't need to check if it did match all of it.
What you still need to do, that I *can't* (since I don't know what you're using), is insert the proper boundary detection after `www`. Probably `\b` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! (can only accept your answer in 9 minutes)

Comment: No problem, I can wait :)

Comment: Wont this mean that the domain name cant contain www? What if it was testwwwttest.blah?

Comment: You can replace `[0-9A-Za-z_-]` with simply `[\w-]` and I think you should accept [Tim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21876644/2936460), not mine.

Answer (score 3):

First, that regex isn't correct, it should be `((?:[0-9A-Za-z_-]+))` (or simply `([\w-]+)` - the non-capturing group is unnecessary). There are some characters between `Z` and `a` that you don't want to match.

Second, use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that the string you're matching isn't `www`. To make sure that we're not just taking the submatch `ww` from `www` (or fail to match `wwwwwhat.sgoing.on`), it might be necessary to add [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), depending on context:

```
\b(?!www\b)([\w-]+)
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks for your explanation, but it accept multiple subdomains (subsubdomain, subsubsubdomain...) and I just one to valid one

Comment: Okay I used the following : (\b(?!www\b)(?:[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)) to don't accept dots

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to validate subdomain.

```
^([a-z0-9]+([\-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?\.){0,}([a-z0-9]+([\-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?){1,63}(\.[a-z0-9]{2,7})+$
```

Comment: This doesn't exclude `www` from the match, which is what was asked **explicitly**.